# What is the correct erb equivalent of the html form?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

I have the following html code for a form. I want to keep the look exactly the way it is except I want to use the erb **form_for** to create a new contact. The form should be handled by the **Contacts controller** and the defined instance variable is called **@contact**. What is the correct erb to keep exactly the same look but instead use

```
 <% form_for @contact do |f| %>
        #code
  <% end %>
```

Below is the original html form. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="contact_from">
                    <form action="#" method="post">
                        <!-- Message Input Area Start -->
                        <div class="contact_input_area">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Your Message *" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn submit-btn">Send Now</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Message Input Area End -->
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put divs inside your rails `form_for` method. And use helpers for creating the input fields.

```
<% form_for @contact, :url => {:action => "#"}, method: 'post' do |f| %>
<div class="contact_from">
  <!-- Message Input Area Start -->
  <div class="contact_input_area">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_field :name, required: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Your Name" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Your E-mail" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_area :message, required: true, :size => "30x4", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Your Message *' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Single Input Area Start -->
      <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn submit-btn">Send Now</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Message Input Area End -->
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below active view form helper:

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

and replace 
`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>` with below active view helper

```
<%= f.text_field :name, required: true, class: 'form-control' %>
```

and do the similar thing for other input tags.

you can keep all the `div`s as is.

Read [this doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for the better understanding.